# How to paint background of part of shape in SVG file?

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

I have a shape I'm doing in my application. This is the shape:

[image]

I'm trying to paint only part of it (the white squares). What is the best approach to it? I thought about drawing every square individually then fill the background of them one by one as I need.

Is there a way to take the SVG file of the whole shape and then background fill just a part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need some way of defining which area you want to fill so you may as well fill the area for the path itself.

In the SVG markup you would do this by identifying the path for you 'white squares' and adding `fill="white"` it will look something like this:

```
<path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z" fill="white"/>
```